# Problem with solving non-linear differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Need some hints where to start with this non-linear differential equations.

$$\ddot{r} = \dot{r} (\dot\varphi)^2 - \frac{2rk}{m}$$

$$\ddot\varphi=-\frac{\dot{r}\dot\varphi}{r}$$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I've fixed up the MathJax code for you; I hope I've gotten it correct to your intended meaning.

Comment: Thank you, Willie Wong! And yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The second equation can be rewritten as $r\ddot\varphi+\dot r\dot\varphi=\frac{d}{dt}\left(r\dot\varphi \right)=0$ and therefore $r\dot\varphi$ is a constant. The rest is clear sailing! By the way, you should try to clarify the context where the problem came from. Is this related to the geodesic equation?

Next, you would substitute $\dot{\varphi}=\frac{c}{r}$ in the first equation, and then multiply by $r$ to get an exact differential again.

You might want to point out that what you are doing with springs and equations of motion is equivalent to solving the geodesic equation (in differential-geometric terms).

Comment: My apology, I'm new to this.
We are trying to describe a system of a mass, with four springs at 90 degrees. These equations come from approximated potential and should be the equations of motion of the mass in polar coordinates due to the central symmetry of the potential. 
But it is still not clear to me, should I substitute $\dot{\varphi}=\frac{c}{r}$ ?

Comment: I amplified my answer.